# How to annotate Jersey POJO when Impl is remote?

Tags: spring, rest, jersey, jax-rs, rmi

I have 2 JVM's.

JettyJVM
Runs http requests and has an interface CarFacade that is backed using RmiProxyFactoryBean to the CarFacadeImpl running in the CoreJVM

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBeanFactory">
  <property name="serviceInterface" value="org.foo.CarFacade"/>
  <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://#{HOST}:1099/CarFacade"/>
</bean>
```

CoreJVM
Runs core business logic in a spring container and has CarFacadeImpl

```
<bean id="carFacade" class="org.foo.impl.CarFacadeImpl"></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">  
  <property name="service" ref="carFacade"></property>  
  <property name="serviceInterface" value="org.foo.CarFacade"></property>  
  <property name="serviceName" value="CarFacade"></property>  
  <property name="replaceExistingBinding" value="true"></property>  
  <property name="registryPort" value="1099"></property>  
</bean>
```

This setup works currently for flex/blazds and my services are exposed nicely.

Is there any way I can also expose this via Jersey?

I tried with the annotations on the Impl (preferred) but the component scan doesn't find the annotations (obviously as the interface doesn't have them)
So I tried with the annotations on the Interface but jersey says it can't instantiate the interface.

```
// CarFacadeImpl.java - when I had the annotations on the class in the CoreJVM
@Path("car")
public class CarFacadeImpl implements CarFacade {
  @GET
  public String getName() {
    return "CarFacade";
  }
}

// CarFacade.java - When I had the annotations on the interface in JettyJVM
@Path("car")
public class CarFacade {
  @GET
  String getName();
}
```

I would really like to not have to write an additional layer just to expose via rest.

I have tried the examples from here http://www.webappsolution.com/wordpress/2012/03/23/one-java-service-pojo-for-amfxmljson-with-spring-blazeds-jersey-jax-rs/ and they work without the RMI call in between.

Comment: Hello! What are you using as marshaller? Anyway, I think that whatever you use you will need an implementation of the class in your JettyJVM (at the end, you want to get an object!). If you use e.g. gson you won't need to add getters and setters, just a constructor. In some others e.g. moxy you will need at least setters and setters.

Comment: @lrnzcig We are just using Jersey's default JSON marshaller annotating the classes with `@XmlRootElement`
Surely there must be a way to use the RmiProxyFactoryBean? I don't mind if I need to implement an extension to Jersey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, at least for Jersey 2.16.  It does require the annotations to be on the interface, but this is far better than creating a whole new layer

Override the default path scanning registration and register using something similar to this:

```
// Jersey ResourceConfig
final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();

// Get my Spring context
final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("clientContext.xml");
// Use Springs class path scanner to find @Path annotated classes
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false) {
    @Override
    protected boolean isCandidateComponent(AnnotatedBeanDefinition beanDefinition) {
        return beanDefinition.getMetadata().isIndependent();
    }
};
scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Path.class));

// For each class found in package (and sub packages)
for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents("example")) {
    try {
        // Get the class
        Class clazz = HttpServer.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(bd.getBeanClassName());
        // Get the proxy
        Object bean = context.getBean(clazz);
        if (bean != null) {
            // Register the proxy with the interface
            rc.register(bean, clazz);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```